# list items display without bullets use text instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I removed the bullet points from an unordered list, and I want to display `Log` with every message but that is not coming up. Any idea what is wrong in the below code, because I want user to see the difference between messages, all messages together user can not see message start and end points. Any other solution to make it better?

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <ul style="list-style: none">
        <li ng-repeat="item in data  | filter:vm.searchLog track by $index" ng-bind-html="item | highlight:vm.searchLog">Log:</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `li::before { content: "Log: "; }` if you want to add it via css.

Comment: Log: will be overwritten by the binding. You could try move the ng-bind-html binding to a span within the li element, with "Log:" before it, or concatenate "Log: " in the binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS :before selector with a content property to insert some text instead of a bullet point

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    content: 'Log';
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/xgxtt9sd/3/) for a Fiddle

Comment: is there way to style `content:'Log' ` i want to make it bold or some different color

Comment: Thanks it helped me!